# Parsing CSV column values from closed list

Tags: pandas, csv

I am trying to load this CSV: https://www.kaggle.com/miroslavsabo/young-people-survey using Pandas
and train a TensorFlow model.
Some of the values inside this csv are from a closed list for example "Smoking" has the possible values "never smoked", "tried smoking", "current smoker".

What I want to do is to automatically create a binary column for each value
So instead of having 1 column with these 3 possible values, I will have 3 columns
"never smoked", "tried smoking", "current smoker",
each column will be filled with 1 if the value inside the original column is the same as the name of the column otherwise it will be zero.

Does tensorflow have some automatic way to do this per each column with values from  closed list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.get_dummies()` is made specially for this. [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

In your case it would be (taking example directly from there)

```
clms = pd.Series(list(["never smoked", "tried smoking", "current smoker"]))
your_pd.get_dummies(clms)
```